# Android Fragment appends when calling other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im currently working on a sample app that will be using fragments, but im having a little problem regarding changing the fragment.

My default layout for my fragment is fragmentOne (see code below).

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fplace"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="498dp"
    android:name="layout.FragmentOne"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fragment_one" />
```

and that's working correctly.

but when im changing the fragment it appends. the behavior must replace the fragment not append.

here is my code for the activity (see code below).

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Button button = (Button) view;
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.f1:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fplace, fragment);
            ft.commit();
            break;
        case R.id.f2:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            fm = getFragmentManager();
            ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fplace, fragment);
            ft.commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

and from the fragment one i am loading the data from the onCreateView() which is working correctly. the main problem is the fragment appends not replace.

(see photo below)

the red and yellow must be replaced by the blue colored fragment

[image]

Comment: You cannot remove/replace `Fragment`s that are declared in your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike said in comment

> You cannot remove/replace Fragments that are declared in your layout.

So here is solution for you. Instead of `fragment` in xml use `framelayout` as container which will hold the `fragment`

use this instead of `fragment` in xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fplace"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="498dp"
    />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This works but i can't format my User interface properly. it looks like crap.

Comment: You can always improve UI. How does it look like now? post the screenshots in question. Also if this answer has helped you then kindly accept it as well.

Comment: i am sure `layout_height` would be issue here. You set `match_parent` as well.

Answer (score 0):

declare a new fragmenttransaction in the second case dont use the fragment transaction  that is used in the first case